# Don't sync bound value of TextField on keyup (wait until item is saved)

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of items and a form that is used to edit the currently selected item. Clicking an item selects it for editing by setting it as the "current" property of the collection controller. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/adamlogic/75fK6/) is a simplified example in a jsfiddle.

My problem is that when editing the current item, changes are reflected in the item after each keyup. I really don't want the item to reflect the changes until "Save" is pressed. Is there a way to suppress bound properties from syncing until I explicitly tell them to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7utu2/1/) that demostrates one way to make a copy and merge the results back into the original object.

The code is below too. I added a copy function (via the Copyable mixin), and a new "merge" function which copies the values from another instance of Project, while preserving the object instance (the other option would be just to replace the entire object).

*I did notice that in the copy function you could do "`return App.Project.create(this)`" and it seemed to work as well experimentally, but I liked the clarity (and certainty) of copying properties specifically.*

```
// By adding Copyable, you're adding the 'copy' mixin
App.Project = Ember.Object.extend(Ember.Copyable, {
    save: function() {
        console.log('saving')
    },
    copy: function(deep) {
        return App.Project.create({
            name: this.get('name'),
            source: this.get('source')
        });
    },
    // grab new values and directly insert them
    // this way, it preserves object identity
    merge: function(source) {
        this.set('name', source.get('name'));
        this.set('source', source.get('source'));
    }
});
```

Here, I added a new property (editCopy) which is used by your ProjectForm in place of current. Once editing is complete and the save is clicked, the data is merged back into the original.

```
App.projectController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    current: null,
    editCopy: null,
    saveCurrent: function() {
        var toSave = this.get('current');
        toSave.merge(this.get('editCopy'));
        toSave.save();
    }
});

App.ProjectEditLink = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function() {
        App.projectController.set('current', this.get('project'));
        App.projectController.set('editCopy', this.get('project').copy());
    }
});

App.ProjectForm = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'project_form_template'
});



App.projectController.pushObject(App.Project.create({
    name: "jQuery",
    source: "jquery.js"
}));
App.projectController.pushObject(App.Project.create({
    name: "Ember",
    source: "ember.js"
}));
App.projectController.pushObject(App.Project.create({
    name: "Backbone",
    source: "backbone.js"
}));
```

Comment: Very nice. This does exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to bind your field values to a copy of the record you are editing. Then, when the user clicks the save button you take those values and copy them back to the original record.

Comment: I think this is the direction I need to go, but I haven't been able to get it working. How would you go about it?

Comment: You can checkout the contacts sample app I was working on at http://contacts.strobeapp.com/. This was before the update to emberjs but the principle should be similar. Basically I create a copy of the object the user selects and populate the view with the copy's data. There are still some bugs, but hopefully that will help  point you in the right direction. [Edit] It looks like WPCoder already gave you an example.